# Using react leaflet version3 gave this kind of errors

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| / required styles /
|

> .leaflet-pane,
> | .leaflet-tile,
> | .leaflet-marker-icon,

i have tried many solution but nothing changes i am stuck here for 3 hours

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-leaflet-tutorial/

**Replace the "browserslist" values in the package.json**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).